# How can I switch between Move/Rotate/Scale with shortcuts without straight altering coordinates?

Tags: shortcut

I'm coming from Cinema4D and there when you hit the shortcuts, you just change the "gizmo" and that's it. Then you can for example slide your object along an axis. But when I hit the shortcut in Blender, I'm straight modifying position in all axises. I almost never want to do that and this is confusing.

I'm using Blender 2.80 Beta

Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gizmo doesn't appear](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207490/gizmo-doesnt-appear)

Answer (score 3):

I just moved to Blender from Maya where the shortcuts also immediately give you the tool's axis to work with rather this free axis movement.

See the tool icons on the left side of the viewport? Simply right click one, select 'Assign Shortcut', and type in the shortcut the tool already uses.

Do this for the *Move*, *Rotate* and *Scale* tools in turn, in both *Object* and *Edit Mode* (and probably any other mode you use). Then bam, no more free form transform, the shortcut will now directly select the tool you're after and nothing more, just as it should!

Answer (score 2):

Blender lets you exclude one axis from transform actions.

Type the letter, <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain after pressing the transform hotkey <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, or <kbd>S</kbd> that you wish.

Or, type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + (letter corresponding to axis to exclude), <kbd>G</kbd> followed by <kbd>X</kbd> would move along the X-axis. <kbd>G</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>  would move along the Y and Z-axis.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I’m not in front of my workstation so I can’t test it right now but that makes some sense. It seems shortcut heavy though. In Cinema 4D there’s little handles between each plane(two axises) that let you move the selected object on two axises and I use them a lot. This means I don’t have to use shortcuts each time I want to move my object between different axises or pair of axises but only the mouse. I don’t recall seeing something similar in Blender.

Comment: Don't know which build you are using, but on mine (2019-02-15) there is a little colored plane between each axis, which acts like you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I come from 3dsmax, and this is driving me mad.

I found a different solution, press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and a small menu will appear with all the tools, and they wont activate the immediate manipulation.

To have this function, you need to go to *Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap -> Spacebar Action -> Tools*.

It's not perfect, it would be better if you can just tap <kbd>R</kbd>  and the gizmo would just show up. (Maybe there is a setting or plugin somewhere?)