# How to activate different tool gizmos with shortcuts?

Tags: transforms, workflow, customization, shortcut, 3d-manipulator

When I use <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, or <kbd>G</kbd> it allows me to interact with the object in all directions but I would like that those commands just activate the respective manipulator.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

thank you for your answer! I've found a solution

Just Right-click on the move, rotate and scale buttons, then "assign shortcut" and you add the respective command

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can access each one of the transform tools individually in the tool bar:

[image]

Or you can enable gizmos individually as well in the viewport gizmos controls

[image]